# How can I use wherehas and join simultaneously?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I use Laravel 5.3

My code is like this :

```
public function getWishlist($param)
{
    $num = 20;
    $q = $param['q'];
    $location = $param['location'];

    $result = $this->product_repository->whereHas('favorites', function ($query) use($q, $location) {
        $query->where('favorites.user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)
              ->where('products.status', '=', 1);

        if($q) 
            $query->where('products.name', 'like', "%$q%");
    })
    ->join('stores', 'stores.id', '=', 'products.store_id');
    if($location)
       $result->where('stores.address', 'like', "%$location%");

    if($q) 
        $result->where('products.name', 'like', "%$q%")
              ->where('stores.address', 'like', "%$q%", 'or');

    dd($result->toSql());
    // ->paginate($num);

    return $result;
}
```

When executed, the result is empty

Seems wherehas and join not work simultaneously

Is there any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: `join()` works fine with `whereHas()`. You need to check your SQL query using `toSql()` method. It may help you to debug the problem.

Comment: @Amit Gupta, I try this : `dd($result->toSql());`. There exist error : `Method toSql does not exist.`

Comment: I hope you are trying `toSql()` before calling `paginate()` method.

Comment: @Amit Gupta, I had update my question. It works. But when the location exist, there exist error like this : `Array to string conversion`

Comment: Not sure about the error. The source of error could be many. Maybe you can go deeper in Laravel's code to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use advanced where

```
$result = $result->where(function($query) use ($q) {
      $query->where('products.name', 'like', "%$q%")
        ->where('stores.address', 'like', "%$q%", 'or');
})
```